# Pass date from shell script to query

Tags: linux, shell, unix, solaris, hive

Below is my shell script from which I am running my Hive query. In this I am calculating the Yesterday's date and I am passing that Yesterday's date in the where clause. But that query is not working for me.

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE_YEST=`TZ=GMT+48 date +%Y%m%d`
echo $DATE_YEST
hive -S -e 'SELECT * FROM PDS_ATTRIBUTE_DATA_REALTIME WHERE dt=$DATE_YEST'
```

I am running the above script like this-

```
sh -x test.sh
```

Is there something wrong with the way I am passing that `DATE_YEST date` in the where clause?

Comment: Try to echo your select statement. See if it looks correct.

Comment: "But that query is not working for me."  --> This is the part you must elaborate on. What error message do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE_YEST=`TZ=GMT+48 date +%Y%m%d`
echo $DATE_YEST
echo "SELECT * FROM PDS_ATTRIBUTE_DATA_REALTIME WHERE dt=$DATE_YEST"
```

Output will be:

```
20120806
SELECT * FROM PDS_ATTRIBUTE_DATA_REALTIME WHERE dt=20120806
```

And if you need the quotes around the select, use this:

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE_YEST=`TZ=GMT+48 date +%Y%m%d`
echo $DATE_YEST
echo "\"SELECT * FROM PDS_ATTRIBUTE_DATA_REALTIME WHERE dt=$DATE_YEST\""
```

Output will be:

```
20120806
"SELECT * FROM PDS_ATTRIBUTE_DATA_REALTIME WHERE dt=20120806"
```

Assuming you want the quotes your script will look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE_YEST=`TZ=GMT+48 date +%Y%m%d`
echo $DATE_YEST
hive -S -e "\"SELECT * FROM PDS_ATTRIBUTE_DATA_REALTIME WHERE dt=$DATE_YEST\""
```